# ¿Porqué se pierde mi estilo de css en diferentes nodos en Drupal 8?

Tags: css, drupal, cms, drupal8

Verán, desde hace unos días comencé a utilizar **Drupal 8** dentro de un proyecto para insertar una sección de noticias que pueda ser editable por miembros de la empresa donde trabajo actualmente.

La cosa es que bajé un template para importarlo a Drupal mediante la maquetación de acuerdo a lo señalado, me carga mi hoja de estilos CSS en la pagina principal (**drupal.dd/**) dentro de mi servidor **Acquia**, pero al agregar un artículo como contenido, evidentemente la página cambia por la siguiente: **drupal.dd/node/numero_de_nodo** y ya no me carga los estilos, he buscado mil formas de agregar mi css a todas las páginas en general y no me funciona, incluso utilicé el **"global-styling"** dentro de mi biblioteca del proyecto y no aplica los estilos para todos los nodos en mi website.
Espero puedan guiarme a resolver ésto.
Muchas gracias.